# "ERROR: Cannot proceed" when trying to encrpyt home directory in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I installed ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup. Then I created a new user and assigned sudo privileges. After that, I tried to to encrypt the main user's home directory and ran into an error.

```
encryption_user@oem-LENOVO-IDEAPAD-100-15IBY:/home/woods$ sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u woods
```

```
INFO:  Checking disk space, this may take a few moments.  Please be patient.
INFO:  Checking for open files in /home/woods

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
INFO:  The following files are in use:

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
    COMMAND      PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
    colord      1470          colord  mem    REG    8,2     1200 10485962 

/home/woods/.local/share/icc/edid-698e05d1ba894b2ef0475b915e6c0444.icc
    pipewire  130186           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    pipewire- 130187           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    pulseaudi 130188           woods  mem    REG    8,2    28672 10485782 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-card-database.tdb
    pulseaudi 130188           woods  mem    REG    8,2    12288 10485781 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-stream-volumes.tdb
    pulseaudi 130188           woods  mem    REG    8,2    12288 10485780 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-device-volumes.tdb
    pulseaudi 130188           woods   10u   REG    8,2    12288 10485780 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-device-volumes.tdb
    pulseaudi 130188           woods   11u   REG    8,2    12288 10485781 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-stream-volumes.tdb
    pulseaudi 130188           woods   12u   REG    8,2    28672 10485782 /home/woods/.config/pulse/00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9-card-database.tdb
    dbus-daem 130197           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfsd     130207           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-docum 130208           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-permi 130216           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gdm-wayla 130271           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gnome-ses 130275           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    tracker-m 130276           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485938 

/home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485883 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485880 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485874 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485871 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485842 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    32768 10485792 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods    8ur  REG    8,2  2867200 10485783 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods    9u   REG    8,2   764120 10485791 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   10ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485792 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   11rr  REG    8,2  2867200 10485783 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   12ur  REG    8,2  2703360 10485870 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   13u   REG    8,2  4231272 10485826 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   14ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485842 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   15ur  REG    8,2  1536000 10485841 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   16u   REG    8,2    20632 10485845 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   17ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485871 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   18ur  REG    8,2  1294336 10485873 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   19u   REG    8,2    16512 10485784 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   20ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485874 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   21ur  REG    8,2  1294336 10485878 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   22u   REG    8,2    16512 10485879 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   23ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485880 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   24ur  REG    8,2  1499136 10485822 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   25u   REG    8,2  4210672 10485882 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   26ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485883 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   27ur  REG    8,2  1294336 10485881 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   28u   REG    8,2    16512 10485937 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db-wal
    tracker-m 130276           woods   29ur  REG    8,2    32768 10485938 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db-shm
    tracker-m 130276           woods   34rr  REG    8,2  2703360 10485870 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   36rr  REG    8,2  1536000 10485841 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   38rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485873 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   40rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485878 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   42rr  REG    8,2  1499136 10485822 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   44rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485881 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   49rr  REG    8,2  2867200 10485783 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/meta.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   51rr  REG    8,2  2703360 10485870 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Documents.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   53rr  REG    8,2  1536000 10485841 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Software.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   55rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485873 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Pictures.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   57rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485878 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Audio.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   59rr  REG    8,2  1499136 10485822 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23FileSystem.db
    tracker-m 130276           woods   61rr  REG    8,2  1294336 10485881 /home/woods/.cache/tracker3/files/http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.api.gnome.org%2Fontology%2Fv3%2Ftracker%23Video.db
    gnome-ses 130343           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gnome-ses 130354           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gnome-ses 130354           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    at-spi-bu 130370           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gnome-she 130372           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gnome-she 130372           woods  mem    REG    8,2  1310728 10485818 /home/woods/.cache/mesa_shader_cache/index
    gnome-she 130372           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    gnome-she 130372           woods  176u   REG    8,2    12288 10486031 /home/woods/.cache/event-sound-cache.tdb.00c1124552ad46cea440d8431cf584d9.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    dbus-daem 130378           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfs-udis 130384           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfs-gpho 130391           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfs-goa- 130395           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    goa-daemo 130399           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    goa-ident 130407           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfs-mtp- 130418           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfs-afc- 130424           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-deskt 130564           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-deskt 130568           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-deskt 130568           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    gnome-she 130570           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    evolution 130581           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    evolution 130592           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfsd-tra 130597           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gjs       130608           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    at-spi2-r 130610           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    sh        130627           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-a11y- 130628           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-color 130631           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-color 130631           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    ibus-daem 130634           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-datet 130636           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-house 130637           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-keybo 130639           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-media 130640           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-power 130642           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-power 130642           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    gsd-print 130644           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-rfkil 130653           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-scree 130657           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-shari 130665           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-smart 130666           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-sound 130671           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-wacom 130672           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    dconf-ser 130697           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    evolution 130698           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    evolution 130698           woods   12u   REG    8,2    86016 10485940 /home/woods/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system/contacts.db
    evolution 130714           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-disk- 130718           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    ibus-memc 130721           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    ibus-exte 130723           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gsd-print 130744           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    ibus-port 130753           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    ibus-engi 130798           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    snap-stor 130805           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2     1392 10486215 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/582/.local/share/icons/hicolor/icon-theme.cache
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2    50856 10486151 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/582/.local/share/icons/Adwaita/icon-theme.cache
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2   327184 10486176 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/582/.local/share/icons/Humanity/icon-theme.cache
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2     2832 10486279 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/fontconfig/f2473cc8dd003abaafc21ef1e7ed9bf7-le64.cache-7
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2    15800 10486278 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/fontconfig/831405742a750632339c34a9cab93857-le64.cache-7
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2    15696 10486277 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/fontconfig/f8a546208970b80868906b7ac7e5c596-le64.cache-7
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2    46128 10498232 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/fontconfig/d9cf0a6d-629e-42d9-8f07-e2d539b6ed27-le64.cache-7
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2  5809629 10508329 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/appstream/components.xmlb
    snap-stor 130805           woods  mem    REG    8,2    42372 10486227 /home/woods/snap/snap-store/582/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled
    gjs       130859           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-deskt 130920           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    xdg-deskt 130920           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    gvfsd-met 130977           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gvfsd-met 130977           woods  mem    REG    8,2    32768 10493763 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-4f9a9533.log
    gvfsd-met 130977           woods  mem    REG    8,2       64 10493713 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root
    gvfsd-met 130977           woods    8r   REG    8,2       64 10493713 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root
    gvfsd-met 130977           woods    9u   REG    8,2    32768 10493763 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-4f9a9533.log
    update-no 133465           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    update-no 133465           woods  mem    REG    8,2    10920 10493358 /home/woods/.config/dconf/user
    gjs       134076           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    gjs       134076           woods  mem    REG    8,2    32768 10516976 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-2e4a145d.log
    gjs       134076           woods  mem    REG    8,2      112 10516674 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
    gjs       134076           woods   18r   REG    8,2      112 10516674 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home
    gjs       134076           woods   19r   REG    8,2    32768 10516976 /home/woods/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-2e4a145d.log
    chrome    134111           woods  cwd    DIR    8,2     4096 10485762 /home/woods
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2 26510576 26870110 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/1aaed37d-d229-4dc1-8206-3897827b8618/global-entities_names
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2  1149370 26870112 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/1aaed37d-d229-4dc1-8206-3897827b8618/word_embeddings
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2 29747719 26869844 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/1aaed37d-d229-4dc1-8206-3897827b8618/global-entities_metadata
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2   655360 10489325 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Network Action Predictor
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    28672 10489583 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases/Databases.db
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   147568 10489516 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Subresource Filter/Indexed Rules/35/9.37.2/Ruleset Data
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2  1048576 10493067 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/CrashpadMetrics-active.pma
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2    81920 10489397 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Shortcuts
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2 12591104 10489089 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/GrShaderCache/GPUCache/data_3
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489088 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/GrShaderCache/GPUCache/data_2
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   532480 10489086 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/GrShaderCache/GPUCache/data_1
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   262512 10489084 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/GrShaderCache/GPUCache/index
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   262512 10489071 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache/index
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   262512 10489095 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/index
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2    47104 10489027 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data For Account
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2    98304 10489014 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Data
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2 16640619 26870477 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/baobdjafbehnhgceapbejnfcfebhoafb/1_0/Cached Theme.pak
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2    45056 10489085 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/GrShaderCache/GPUCache/data_0
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489081 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache/data_3
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489080 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache/data_2
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   270336 10489079 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache/data_1
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2    45056 10489576 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/WebStorage/QuotaManager
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    16384 10489010 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/heavy_ad_intervention_opt_out.db
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2  1409024 10489062 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Favicons
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2  2293760 10488997 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2    20480 10499362 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extension Cookies
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489076 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/ShaderCache/GPUCache/data_0
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489099 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/data_3
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489098 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/data_2
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2   270336 10489097 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/data_1
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     8192 10489096 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/data_0
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2    32768 10489026 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Affiliation Database
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-w  REG    8,2    47104 10489028 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data
    chrome    134111           woods  mem-r  REG    8,2    20480 10489092 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Top Sites
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2    53072 10517024 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/945677eb7aeaf62f1d50efc3fb3ec7d8-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     1928 10488984 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/3f589640d34b7dc9042c8d453f7c8b9c-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     2176 10488983 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/16c2fda60d1b4b719f4b3d06fd951d25-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2    25624 10488982 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/3047814df9a2f067bd2d96a2b9c36e5a-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     3384 10488981 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/b9d506c9ac06c20b433354fa67a72993-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     2016 10488980 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/6b2c5944714ca7831b25bed9e85cb5c8-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     9368 10488978 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/f259c2cffa685e28062317905db73c4a-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     5504 10488977 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/550f3886151c940c12a5ed35f6a00586-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2  4194304 10492853 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-63091ADB-20BDF.pma
    chrome    134111           woods  mem    REG    8,2     1920 10488979 /home/woods/.cache/fontconfig/551ecf3b0e8b0bca0f25c0944f561853-le64.cache-7
    chrome    134111           woods   14u   REG    8,2  4194304 10492853 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-63091ADB-20BDF.pma
    chrome    134111           woods   49w   REG    8,2      289 10487121 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/LOG
    chrome    134111           woods   50uW  REG    8,2        0 10489024 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/LOCK
    chrome    134111           woods   65uW  REG    8,2        0 10489150 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Session Storage/LOCK
    chrome    134111           woods   66u   REG    8,2   131072 10489100 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Visited Links
    chrome    134111           woods   67uw  REG    8,2  2293760 10488997 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
    chrome    134111           woods   69uw  REG    8,2  1409024 10489062 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Favicons
    chrome    134111           woods   70w   REG    8,2       41 10489019 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Site Characteristics Database/MANIFEST-000001
    chrome    134111           woods   71w   REG    8,2      313 10486438 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Site Characteristics Database/LOG
    chrome    134111           woods   72uW  REG    8,2        0 10489018 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Site Characteristics Database/LOCK
    chrome    134111           woods   73r   REG    8,2 16640619 26870477 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/baobdjafbehnhgceapbejnfcfebhoafb/1_0/Cached Theme.pak
    chrome    134111           woods   74w   REG    8,2    24603 10489061 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Site Characteristics Database/000003.log
    chrome    134111           woods   75u   REG    8,2    32768 10489026 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Affiliation Database
    chrome    134111           woods   76w   REG    8,2       41 10489025 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/MANIFEST-000001
    chrome    134111           woods   77uw  REG    8,2    47104 10489027 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data For Account
    chrome    134111           woods   78w   REG    8,2    94511 10489065 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/000003.log
    chrome    134111           woods   79uw  REG    8,2    47104 10489028 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data
    chrome    134111           woods   80r   REG    8,2   451968 10489126 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Dictionaries/en-US-10-1.bdic
    chrome    134111           woods   81uw  REG    8,2    98304 10489014 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web Data
    chrome    134111           woods   82uW  REG    8,2        0 10488995 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb/LOCK
    chrome    134111           woods   83ur  REG    8,2    20480 10489092 /home/woods/.config/google-chrome/Default/Top Sites
    chrome    134111           woods   89r   REG    8,2   147568 10489516 

ERROR:  Cannot proceed.
```

I had to delete half of it for it to fit. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Only full disk encryption is recommended nowadays.

Comment: ok thanks didnt want to reinstall but may just have to.